# Show review file word by C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have project print file word using C#.

I have active a document and call `PrintPreview()` but it don't show anything. I try to change type view of document but it don't show too

I want to show print review before i print it but it doén't work :(

My code:

```
void PrintFileWord(string p_strPath)
    {
        object v_objFilename = p_strPath;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application v_appAC = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document v_doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        object v_objReadOnly = false;
        object v_objIsVisible = true;
        object v_objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            if (v_doc.Application.WindowState == WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize){
                ((_Document)v_doc).Close();
            }
            v_doc = v_appAC.Documents.Open(ref v_objFilename,
                            ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing,
                            ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing,
                            ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing,
                            ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing, ref v_objMissing);
            v_appAC.PrintPreview = true;
            v_doc.Activate();
            v_doc.PrintPreview();
            ((_Document)v_doc).Close();
            ((_Application)v_appAC).Quit();
    }
```

I hope someone else can help me solve it.

Comment: where are you using v_objIsVisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the application visible - add this :

```
v_appAC.Visible = true;
```

PrintPreview mode can be shown by either setting the PrintPreview property OR calling the PrintPreview method - it is not necessary to do both.

It is possible to simplify your code to this :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application v_appAC = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document v_doc;
v_doc = v_appAC.Documents.Open(p_strPath);
v_appAC.Visible = true;
v_appAC.PrintPreview = true;
v_doc.Close();
v_appAC.Quit();
```

Comment: If it was my answer that fixed your problem then you should mark it as correct - that way it is highlighted as answered if someone else searches for a similar problem.

Comment: ya i did it :D :D